# Wanting to export mesh from substance painter to blender

Tags: export, workflow, texture-baking

Blender baking capabilities were giving me trouble so i decided to use substance painter to bake high poly details onto a low poly mesh.

Now i’m having trouble exporting the new low poly mesh back into blender, from substance painter, while maintaining the details.

Any suggestions? Thanks